# Finding minimum value of relation with quadratic coefficient

Tags: quadratics

Let $f(x)= ax^2 +bx+c$, such that $f(x)\geq0$. Find minimum value of $\frac{f(1)}{f(0)-f(-1)}.$

My attempt: denominator should be maximum
so $f(-1)=0$  as $f(x)$ is always greater than or equal to zero. So I got $b=2a$, $c=a$. But then I am getting the answer as $4$ whereas the answer is $3$.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. It is unclear.

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ iff $a \geq 0$ and $b^{2} \leq 4ac$. You have to minimize $\frac {a+b+c} {b-a}$ subject to these conditions.

Comment: yes . that is to be minimised. so i took f(-1) as 0. but i got wrong ans.

Answer (score 1):

Wlog we can assume $a=1$. So the task becomes to minimize $F(b,c)=\frac{1+b+c}{b-1
}$ with $b^2\leq4c$.
Let us start by taking the derivative with respect to $c$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial c}=\frac{1}{b-1}=0$. We see that we have no extremal points. So we turn to the boundary $F(b,\tfrac{b^2}{4})$. Again looking for extremal points we differentiate this time with respect to $b$ and end up with $\frac{b^2-2b-8}{4(b-1)^2}=0$ which implies $b\in\{-2,4\}$. Inserting yields $F(-2,1)=0$ and $F(4,4)=3$.